# Flask: Form value to trigger second python script

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have read many other answers here, but find that following them doesn't still work for me.

What I want is for one python script which runs Flask to get a value submitted from an html form, and then pass it into an argument for a second python script that is triggered from the first python script.

My python Flask code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Webapp.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import datetime
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("my-form.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['field1']
    mid = text.upper()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeString = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    IDData = {
    'title' : mid,
    'time': timeString
    }
    print('ID is: {0}'.format(mid))
    os.system("sudo python /home/pi/Add/triggertest.py mid")
    return render_template('cp.html', **IDData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logfile.close()
```

My html for index file is as below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HEAT</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/style.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="/logo.png" alt="LOGO" style="width:168px;height:56px;">
    <h1>"HEAT"</h1>
    <div id="time">
        <h3>The current date and time on the server is: {{ time }}</h3>
    </div>
    <!--
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function autoRefresh_div()
            {
                $("#time").load("cp.html");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
            }
            setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 0500); // refresh div after 0.5 secs
        </script>
    -->
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
        <li><label>Melt ID <span class="required">*</span></label></li>
        <li>
        <input type="text" name="field1" class="field-divided" placeholder="Please enter the meltID here"/>
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My cp.html is as below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Control Panel</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/style.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="time">
        <!--
        <code>
    @app.route('/my-form', methods=['POST'])
        def my_form_post():
            text = request.form['field1']
            processed_text = text.upper()
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            timeString = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
            IDData = {
                'title' : processed_text,
                'time': timeString
                }
            return render_template('cp.html', **IDData)</code>-->

    <h3>The melt ID is: {{ IDData }}</h3>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My code for second python script triggertest.py is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

# For logging debug output:
#import logging
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import time
import os
import sys
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MAX31855.MAX31855 as MAX31855
from datetime import datetime

# Define a function to convert celsius to fahrenheit.
def c_to_f(c):
        return c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0

# Raspberry Pi software SPI configuration.
#CLK = 25
#CS  = 24
#DO  = 18
#sensor = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, CS, DO)

# Raspberry Pi hardware SPI configuration.
SPI_PORT   = 0
SPI_DEVICE = 0
sensor = MAX31855.MAX31855(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))

def write_temp(t, logfile):
    #Writes temperature as .3 float to open file handle.
    logfile.write('{},{:.3f}\n'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), t))

def loop(t, logfile):
    #Starts temperature logging until user interrupts.
    while True:
        #temp = sensor.readTempC()
        t = sensor.readTempC()
        if t:
            write_temp(t, logfile)
#print('Current temperature: {0:.3f} Â°C'.format(t))
            sys.stdout.flush() #Flush. Btw, print is time-consuming
            time.sleep(.25)

# Instructions for exiting the program
print('Trigger testing in progress. Press Ctrl-C to quit.')  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The next two lines are for using DS18B20 temperature sensor
    # Take the first match for a device that is not 'w1_bus_master1'
    #dev = [d for d in os.listdir('/sys/bus/w1/devices') if d != 'w1_bus_master1'][0]
    # Prepare the log filename
    fname = str(sys.argv[1]) + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")+".csv"
    # Immediately open the log in append mode and do not close it
    logfile = open(fname, 'a')

    try:
        # Only pass device and file handle, not the file name.
        t = sensor.readTempC()
        internal = sensor.readInternalC()
        loop(t, logfile)
        print('Thermocouple Temperature: {0:0.3F}*C / {1:0.3F}*F'.format(t, c_to_f(temp)))
        print('    Internal Temperature: {0:0.3F}*C / {1:0.3F}*F'.format(internal, c_to_f(internal)))
        #time.sleep(1.0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Close log file on exit
        logfile.close()
```

My problems are:

1. Script #2 (triggertest.py which logs temperature) is starting, but it is not logging anything. I guess because the argument is not being passed?
2. I can end script #2 with Ctrl-C, but script #1 with flask remains running, which makes me need to restart the raspberry pi to run/test everything again.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have put 4 codes here making this file too long, and I apologize for that. I am a newbie to HTML and Python, and hence stuck here.

Comment: This is not a very good practice. You should instead `import triggertest` and then have a function in `triggertest` which can return the measurements for you.

Comment: If you suspect that you are not passing arguments to second script replace  `os.system("sudo python /home/pi/Add/triggertest.py mid")` with 
`subprocess.call(["python /home/pi/Add/triggertest.py", mid])`

Comment: @msvalkon, thanks for the input, I will review the import option and try it out.

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov, subprocess is giving me errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/Add/Webapp.py", line 48, in my_form_post
    subprocess.call(["python /home/pi/Add/triggertest.py", mid])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception